# Ajax request not working in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-ajax

This code runs in Visual Studio but not in IIS.

```
$('#addMessage').click(function () {
    var textMessage = $('#ticketMessage').val();
    var isInternal = $('#isInternal')[0].checked;
    var ticketID = $('#TicketID').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Ticket/AddMessage',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { textMessage: textMessage, isInternal: isInternal, ticketID: ticketID },
        success: function (data) {
            var tbody = $('#allMessages').children()[0];
            tbody.innerHTML = tbody.innerHTML + data;
            $('#ticketMessage').val("");
            $('#isInternal')[0].checked = false;
        }
    });
});
```

What to fix in this code for the ajax request to run properly in IIS?

Comment: Is your application sitting in an IIS Application, or a virtual folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check with URL, Because sometimes the URL may point to 404 error page.
Because, the file is hosted in virtual folder. So, Please try with fully URL first, to check if it work fine. Better use Firebug or IE 9 developer tools. we can trace the Ajax requests.

I mean like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/yourapplication/Ticket/AddMessage',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { textMessage: textMessage, isInternal: isInternal, ticketID: ticketID },
    success: function (data) {
    var tbody = $('#allMessages').children()[0];
    tbody.innerHTML = tbody.innerHTML + data;
    $('#ticketMessage').val("");
    $('#isInternal')[0].checked = false;
    }
});
```